# getting error undefined reference to `int*__errno_location()' on building a binary

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a server file utcserr.ser and I'm getting the error : 
lib4eye.so: undefined reference to `int*__errno_location()'.
I was able to build lib4eye.so successfully without any error.

But if I try to see __errno_location in lib4eye.so, it shows as undefined.

Output of **"nm -AC lib4eye.so | grep errno_location"**  is :

```
lib4eye.so:         U __1cQ__errno_location6F_pi_
```

The included header **errno.h** contains the following code :

```
extern int *__errno_location (void) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
#   define errno (*__errno_location ())
```

I've also tried to link libpthread.so and libc.so  but no use. The error still persists.

Also, we are building on 32-bit Linux environment.

Kindly help.

For building lib4eye.so, I'm using the following command :

> CC -m32 -g -G -KPIC -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

where $OBJECTS is the path of where all .o's are placed.

For building the server "utcserr.ser"  , I'm using the command :

> buildserver -v -r Oracle_XA \
>   -o $BIN/utcserr \
>   -f $HOME/COMM_BROOT/MEM/obj/main_mem.o \
>   -f $HOME/ARCH_SVR/utcserr/obj/err.o \
>   -f $HOME/ARCH_SVR/utcserr/obj/eut0101.o \
>   -f -lQZ_RPC \
>   -f -lQZXML \
>   -f -ldm \
>   -f -l4eye \
>   -f -lpthread-2.12 \
>   -f -lc-2.12 \
>   -f -lstt \
>   -f -lmem \
>   -f -lQlog \
>   -f -lutil \
>   -f -lAudit \
>   -f -lobj \
>   -f -ldmstd \
>   -f -lAtrAuth \
>   -f -lARCHrbe \
>   -f -lQZ_UTIL \
>   -f -ltuxreal \
>   -f -lxlerr \
>   -f $HOME/GENCODE/lib/linux/ARCH_lib.a \
>   -f $HOME/GENCODE/lib/linux/QZ_lib.a \
>   -f -lxlse \
>   -f -lqz \
>   -f -lxlclass \
>   -f -lclass \
>   -f -lcfiles \
>   -f -lutil \
>   -b shm \
>   -s EUT0101_Diagnos \
>   -s INFORM_ERROR \
>   -s SHUTDOWN

Comment: Can you please tell us *how* you build your program and your library? What commands are you using? What arguments? Please copy-paste the commands exactly as they are into the body of the question.

Comment: For building lib4eye.so,  I'm using the following command :

Comment: Please don't put the commands in comments, *edit your question* to include the commands instead. That's where crucial information belongs.

Comment: For building lib4eye.so,  I'm using the following command :                    **"CC -m32 -g -G -KPIC -o $@ $(OBJECTS)"**    where $OBJECTS  is the path of where all .o's are placed.

Comment: Have added the information in question details

Comment: My guess would be that libraries are linked in the wrong order, and some function relying on errno_location is linked AFTER the C library which contains it. Check the actual compilation line - e.g. add `-v` to the compile command (typically done by adding `-v` to CFLAGS in the build script)

Comment: The order is correct. Have seen this already. :(

Comment: libpthread-2.12.so and  libc-2.12.so are present at path /lib. Rest all at some other path. These were not included earlier in utcserr.ser file. I included them explicitly . Somehow system is not able to link to these libraries.